# Rails query based on custom method

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Is there any better way to find for a record based on custom model method?

```
def search
 payments = all_payments.plans.order('payments.created_at DESC').select do |payment|
   payment.plan == query
 end
 payments.paginate(pagination_params)
end
```

this takes and loads the entire table so the query is very slow.

`payment.plan` is an accessor from the model.

I can't afford to put a limit because it's unfair to the old records from the database.

Any idea? Thanks!

Comment: You have try with eager loading concept here. try to include all your relational model. [Eager Loading](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html#eager-loading-associations)

Comment: You have to translate `payment.plan == query` to SQL so that the query logic can be in the database (where it belongs) and the database can do the work. But we don't know anything about `plan` or `query` so...

Answer (score 0):

How about this:

```
payments = all_payments.plans.where(plan: query).order('payments.created_at DESC').paginate(pagination_params)
```

Comment: will this work even if `plan` is just an accessor attribute?

Comment: I don't think so. I'm getting `Mysql2::Error: Unknown column 'payments.plan'`

Comment: No. It would be looking for a table column.

Comment: Appreciate the help but the attribute is not a part of my table. Haven't tried squeel

Comment: I don't think that Squeel will help either. Without having the data in the database, you'll need to pull all the records back to compare them.